# Add or Remove ng-controller

Tags: html, angularjs

My problem is i need to execute multiple times one controller, but i need to control that action. How can i add or remove an `ng-controller` from html tag. For example i have controller with name `view` and i need an `<div ng-controller="view">` but i need a method to toggle it to `<div>`. On toggle would be better to delete the controller that took place, but i think angular do that automatically Any idea, perhaps something with directives?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a directive instead of a controller. Controllers are not meant to be set and removed like this, the only way to do so would be to recompile the HTML each time which would bring more problems than it solves.

In short, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please try to step back and formulate what problem exactly you are trying to resolve.

Comment: angular-ui-router do it somehow, if i do it threw directive, how i should handle the directive to be toggled? something with add remove attribute from `div`?

Comment: Oh oh, I misunderstoof your problem, if you want to implement routing then you answered yourself: you need to have a look at ngRoute or the one from Angular UI. Try to implement a basic routing by following a tutorial and then ask a specific question if you face any issue, StackOverflow is not designed for open discussions.

Comment: You understand well the problem, just i saw in routing that, they run controller on specific state. And each time they change page they change controller.